# How to tell whether a Type is a list or array or IEnumerable or

Tags: c#, reflection

What's the easiest way, given a `Type` object, to test to see whether it is actually a list of objects?  I.e. Array or IEnumerable/IEnumerable<>.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Check `typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(type)`.

Every collection type, including arrays and `IEnumerable<T>`, implements `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Thanks - I had to exclude `string`, because that came up as an array of `Char` and I didn't want that. :)

Comment: Also exclude System.Xml.XmlText as well as other descendants of System.Xml.XmlNode.

Comment: Note: `IEnumerable` is recognized in the `System.Collections.Generic;` namespace but to be able to use this piece of code it requires to also add `using System.Collections;` otherwise we get the compile error `using the generic type IEnumerable<T> requires 1 type argument` and Visual Studio doesn't even propose to use this namespace

Answer (score 1):

```
typeof(IEnumerable<object>).IsAssignableFrom(propertyInfo.PropertyType)
```

If we are verifying from Generic T.

Answer (score 1):

This does not exactly answers the question but I think this is a helpful code for those who landed on this post.

**Given an *object* or an *IList<T>***, you can use the following code to **check whether the object is an array**.

```
IList<string> someIds = new string[0];
if (someIds is Array)
{
    // yes!
}

IList<string> someIds = new List<string>(0);
if (someIds is Array)
{
    // nop!
}
```

The difference here is that we are not working with any `Type` object but on the *actual* objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (objType.IsArray || objType.IsGenericType)
{

}
```

Comment: `objType.IsGenericType` would return `true`, if it's `int?` and `Nullable<int>` is not an `IEnumerable` or `Array`

Comment: @MatthiasBurger I tested it it returned false

Comment: @AlaMusleh It does return True for int?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using pattern matching.
Like in this sample method:

```
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items)
{
    if (items == null)
        return true;

    if (items is T[] arr)
        return arr.Length == 0;

    return !items.Any();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which deals with classifying a `Type`, not a value. In your example, you already know it's `IEnumerable<T>` because that's the parameter type.

Answer (score -9):

Simple. The easiest thing to do is the following:

```
IList<T> listTest = null;

try{
     listTest = ((IList<T>)yourObject);
}
catch(Exception listException)
{
    //your object doesn't support IList and is not of type List<T>
}

IEnumerable<T> enumerableTest = null;

try{
     enumerableTest = ((IEnumerable<T>)yourObject);
}
catch(Exception enumerableException)
{
     //your object doesn't suport IEnumerable<T>;
}
```

==================================================

You can also try this which doesn't involve multiple try/catch blocks. It's better if you can avoid using those because each condition is actually evaluated by the runtime during runtime... it's bad code (though sometimes there's no way around it).

```
Type t = yourObject.GetType();

if( t is typeof(List<OjbectType>) )   //object type is string, decimal, whatever...
{
     // t is of type List<ObjectType>...
}
else if( t is typeof(IEnumerable<ObjectType>)
{
     // t is of type IEnumerable<ObjectType>...
}
else
{
    // t is some other type.
    // use reflection to find it.
}
```

Comment: Instead of doing `listTest = ((IList<T>)yourObject);` and catching an exception, you can just do `yourObject is IList<T>`

Comment: Wow what a mess.  At least four things badly wrong here.  (1) Catching exceptions instead of using `is` or `as`.  (2) Catching `Exception` instead of `InvalidCastException`.  (3) In the second code block, thinking C# `is` works the same way as VB6 `Is` -- actually `==` is the right operator, but it will still fail because (4) `GetType()` always returns a concrete class, never ever an interface like `IEnumerable<ObjectType>`